spring build-image does not work with DOCKER_HOST different than /var/run/docker.sock
It looks like spring-boot:build-image does not respect the DOCKER_HOST environment variable which is on my host: unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock

Ubuntu Installation
Installation of Docker CE
Checkout https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic
echo $DOCKER_ENV => returns unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock
Run ./mvnw spring-boot:build-image

Following error is shown:
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.3.4:build-image (default-cli) @ spring-petclinic ---
[INFO] Building image 'docker.io/library/spring-petclinic:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO] 
[INFO]  > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled builder image 'paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base@sha256:4dac2a913d951b4f53d6fbfccabeb2c32324f9f8babbf6b78f4129cb60d1373e'
[INFO]  > Pulling run image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run-jammy-base:latest' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled run image 'paketobuildpacks/run-jammy-base@sha256:899201ebad25544171c62c8316d7726dd90df32564a8d29c18656e27729a117c'
[INFO]  > Executing lifecycle version v0.20.3
[INFO]  > Using build cache volume 'pack-cache-e76efea4b23a.build'
[INFO] 
[INFO]  > Running creator
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> ANALYZING
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to initialize analyzer: getting previous image: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.45/version": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

How can I configure build-image task to use the right value from $DOCKER_HOST ?
I tested also to set the host in the maven plugin:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <docker>
      <host>unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock</host>
   </docker>
  </configuration>
</plugin>


Is it maybe related to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32000 which is part of upcoming Spring 3.4.x?

Seems to work with this spring-boot-maven-plugin configuration:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <docker>
      <host>${env.DOCKER_HOST}</host>
      <bindHostToBuilder>true</bindHostToBuilder>
    </docker>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.x/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.examples.docker.podman
Update (10.11.2024):
Actually setting <bindHostToBuilder>true</bindHostToBuilder> is enough (thx Scott Frederick):
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <docker>
      <bindHostToBuilder>true</bindHostToBuilder>
    </docker>
  </configuration>
</plugin>


This is correct, although I don't think it is necessary to configure <host> to explicitly use the environment variable.

There are two main steps to building an image with the Spring Boot Maven or Gradle plugin. First, the Spring Boot plugin code pulls a builder image, a run image, and possibly buildpack images. Then the plugins start a Docker container using the build image and run commands in that container (this is where all the real image building happens).

The Spring Boot plugin code and the code in the builder image both default to \var\run\docker.sock to talk to the Docker daemon. Setting DOCKER_HOST environment variable or the docker.host build plugin configuration tells the Spring Boot plugin code where to find the Docker daemon. Setting <bindHostToBuilder>true</bindHostToBuilder> tells the Spring Boot plugin code to pass the host to the container to override the default used there.

Thank you, @ScottFrederick, for your explanations. Indeed, <bindHostToBuilder>true</bindHostToBuilder> is enough.
